# Rails passenger production error logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, logging

I just deployed a rails app using passenger. Now i am getting a 404 on one of the pages. I am wondering where can i get the error logs. Like the one i get on the dev envirionment when running `rails s` or like the one heroku gives when issues `heroku logs`.

P.S I have looked into production.log but it shows no errors

Update - This is my sample vh config and nothing is there in the error logs

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
     ServerName example.org
     ServerAlias www.example.org
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.org/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the 404 page the Rails 404 page, or an apache/nginx 404 page? If it doesn't look like the rails 404 page, then your best bet is the apache/nginx log.

Comment: it does look like the or infact it is the rails 404 page and i am running apache

Comment: what is the URL being requested?

Comment: domain.com/users . Its the devise url

Comment: Your apache config has /srv/www/example.org/public_html/ -- but that's non standard for an apache/passenger setup. Is that the public directory of your app? (usually something like /u/apps/yourappname/current/public)

Comment: yes i have set it. accordingly the rest of the website shows up but i cant sign up with devise